# Ruby Looking Array of hash Performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, performance, hash

Currently I face this question 
For example I have this array of hash

```
data = [
  {:id => 1,:start_date => "2015-01-02",:end_date => "2015-01-05"},
  {:id => 2,:start_date => "2015-01-06",:end_date => "2015-01-07"},
  {:id => 3,:start_date => "2015-01-10",:end_date => "2015-01-20"}
]
```

So I want to find the exact hash that have "2015-01-04" in range of above hashes's start_date and end_date

Follow the document I find out there are 3 ways to do this

1) Use select

```
finding_hash = data.select {|h| h[:start_date] <= "2015-01-04" && h[:end_date] >= "2015-01-04"}
```

finding_hash will return an array of needed hash
But as i do this,i assure that there will always only one hash match the condition do after do this SELECT
i have to `finding_hash.first` to get the hash i want

2)Use find

```
finding_hash = data.find{|h| h[:start_date] <= "2015-01-04" && h[:end_date] >= "2015-01-04"}
```

This way of doing ,the finding_hash IS the result hash i need

3)Traditional loop

```
data.each do |t|
  if (t[:start_date] <= "2015-01-04" && t[:end_date] >= "2015-01-04")
    return t
    break
  end
end
```

---

So which one is the fastest way to do this.I do need the performance because my data is quite big!

Thank you and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: If your data is quite big then you should throw it in a database and index it. Even SQLite would probably eat up something like this.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the hashes in the array are sorted by date?

Comment: @spickermann : no,it is random my friend

Comment: So you have three pieces of code and you want to know which is fastest. Why don't you *measure* the performance?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : im sorry,i dont know the proper way to do it so i add new 2 values start_time and end_time.and in the end of each code,i put out end_time - start_time ,but it didnt work out so well...

Comment: Use this http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

Answer (score 2):

You can test by [benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html)

For example:

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 1000000

data = [
  {:id => 1,:start_date => "2015-01-02",:end_date => "2015-01-05"},
  {:id => 2,:start_date => "2015-01-06",:end_date => "2015-01-07"},
  {:id => 3,:start_date => "2015-01-10",:end_date => "2015-01-20"}
]


Benchmark.bm do |x|

x.report { n.times do
   data.select {|h| h[:start_date] <= "2015-01-04" && h[:end_date] >= "2015-01-04"}
   end
}

x.report { n.times do
 data.find{|h| h[:start_date] <= "2015-01-04" && h[:end_date] >= "2015-01-04"}
  end

 }

x.report {
n.times do
   finding_hash = {}
   data.each do |t|
     if (t[:start_date] <= "2015-01-04" && t[:end_date] >= "2015-01-04")
       finding_hash = t
       break
     end
    end
end
}

end
```

output:

```
       user     system      total        real
   1.490000   0.020000   1.510000 (  1.533589)
   1.070000   0.010000   1.080000 (  1.096578)
   1.000000   0.010000   1.010000 (  1.011021)
```

Test results is related to the value of n and the data size.

Comment: @DuongBach: don't post "thank you" comments. Upvote is the best thanks (if you truly think it's helpful)

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev, sorry, I found the mistake, i will correct

Answer (score 2):

All the methods you've tried are `Enumerable` methods, but the native `Array` methods are faster. Try [`find_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-find_index).  Even after having to make a separate call to load the hash it's still about 20% faster than the next fastest:

```
index = data.find_index {|h| h[:start_date] <= "2015-01-04" && h[:end_date] >= "2015-01-04"}
x = data[index]
```

My benchmarks:

```
n = 1_000_000

data = [
  {:id => 1,:start_date => "2015-01-02",:end_date => "2015-01-05"},
  {:id => 2,:start_date => "2015-01-06",:end_date => "2015-01-07"},
  {:id => 3,:start_date => "2015-01-10",:end_date => "2015-01-20"}
]

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report 'Enumerable#select' do
    n.times do
      data.select do |h|
        h[:start_date] <= "2015-01-04" && h[:end_date] >= "2015-01-04"
      end
    end
  end

  x.report 'Enumerable#detect' do
    n.times do
      data.detect do |h|
        h[:start_date] <= "2015-01-04" && h[:end_date] >= "2015-01-04"
      end
    end
  end

  x.report 'Enumerable#each  ' do
    n.times do
      finding_hash = {}
      data.each do |t|
        if (t[:start_date] <= "2015-01-04" && t[:end_date] >= "2015-01-04")
          finding_hash = t
          break t
        end
      end
    end
  end

  x.report 'Array#find_index ' do
    n.times do
       index = data.find_index {|h| h[:start_date] <= "2015-01-04" && h[:end_date] >= "2015-01-04"}
       x = data[index]
    end
  end
end
```

Results are:

```
Enumerable#select  1.000000   0.010000   1.010000 (  1.002282)
Enumerable#detect  0.790000   0.000000   0.790000 (  0.797319)
Enumerable#each    0.620000   0.000000   0.620000 (  0.627272)
Array#find_index   0.520000   0.000000   0.520000 (  0.515691)
```

Answer (score 1):

v3 is fastest:

```
def v1
  @data.select {|h| h[:start_date] <= "2015-01-04" && h[:end_date] >= "2015-01-04"}
end

def v2
  @data.find{|h| h[:start_date] <= "2015-01-04" && h[:end_date] >= "2015-01-04"}
end

def v3
  @data.each do |t|
    if (t[:start_date] <= "2015-01-04" && t[:end_date] >= "2015-01-04")
      return t
      break
    end
  end
end
```

`select` will always be slowest because it has to iterate through the entire array. I'm not sure why `find` is slower than v3. It may have to do with overhead.

However, `find` and v3 may be the same for your data. The results below are not necessarily valid for your data.

```
t = Time.now; 10000.times{ v1 }; Time.now - t
=> 0.014131

t = Time.now; 10000.times{ v2 }; Time.now - t
=> 0.013138

t = Time.now; 10000.times{ v3 }; Time.now - t
=> 0.008799
```

Running this on the sample data is not the same thing as running it on your real data.

If the real data is too large, you can run it on a subset of the data to get a better answer.

BTW, you can rewrite v3 as:

```
data.each do |t|
  break t if (t[:start_date] <= "2015-01-04" && t[:end_date] >= "2015-01-04")
end
```

FWIW, operating on an array is going to be very unwieldy and slow. You may want to save it in a database and run a query. For a large dataset, that would probably be at least 2 orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 1):

All those variants are O(n) complexity. 
If your ranges are not overlapping you can use `bsearch` of array which is O(log n) complexity. You should sort your ranges at first.

```
sorted = data.sort_by { |x| x[:start_date] }
sorted.bsearch { |x| ..check if range of `x` includes value.. }
```